# Better approach for SSO to cater windows integrated auth as well as users not on domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, single-sign-on

This may be a duplicate(not sure), but since I am unable to quench my thirst for the right answer (0: so here it goes:

I have to provide single signon for my asp.net web application. Where:

**Case 1.** User is allowed to login without credentials, if the user is already on domain (logged on windows domain).

**Case 2.** User is allowed to login if the user is not on domain, by asking/validating the user login credentials from active directory.

**Question 1a.** I would be interested in the comments about the steps that I "am following" and "should follow" to achieve the requirement. How can I improve this? Improve meaning, is this the right way/approach of providing the above required functionality?

**Question 1b.** Also, currently I have hard coded roles in my database; I am planning to move it within the active directory user roles; so that I could use .IsInRole method functionality. What do you think about that?

Right now, I have implemented it in the following way.

**For case 1, the application uses:**
Windows authentication; basically like following:

```
return ((WindowsIdentity)(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity)).IsAuthenticated;
```

The application proceeds if its an authenticated user.

**For case 2, the application:**
Provides page that asks for domain name, user id, and password.
Checks if the user exists on active directory; following is a snip.

```
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + username + ")";
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
```

The application proceeds if it finds a record of the user.

Please note that this includes the changes recommended in the web.config file, like following snip:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms  loginUrl="~/UI/Pages/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx"  name="adAuthCookie" timeout="60" path="/" />
</authentication>

<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
<identity impersonate="true"/>
```

Seems like adding roles(admin, supervisor, guest) to active directory roles is much better, but then when I would deploy my application how would I go about adding those hard coded roles in active directory? Well.. just thinking out loud.

Answer (score 0):

I had to research this a few months back, and found an excellent article on how to mix Forms and Windows Security in ASP.NET.  I never got the chance to implement it, so I am unsure as to actual results.  If you use any of this, please let me know how it works out for you.

[Mixing Forms and Windows Security in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972958.aspx)